# Why does echo display variables as their names, and also the code following ";?

Tags: php, html, string, echo, double-quotes

These are my problems:
Note: the single queotes (') are not actually displayed
echo $variable; returns nothing
echo "$variable" returns '$variable'
 returns 'stuff"; code ?'

this problem appears both in a portable version of Chrome and in Firefox

here is my code for reference:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html  lang = "it" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name = "keywords" content = "catcher, gioco, top, 10">
        <meta name="author" content="Luca Ballarati">
        <?php require 'connessione'; ?>
        <title> TOP 10 </title>
    </head>
    <body style = "background-color: white;">
        <h1>PROVA:</h1>
        <?php
            apri_conn();

            mysqli_select_db($con,"catcher");
            $sql="SELECT Username, Record FROM utenti ORDER BY Record LIMIT 10";
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            chiudi_conn();

            echo '<b><center><h2>TOP 10 GIOCATORI e RECORD</h2></center></b><br><br>.';
        ?>
        <?php
            $i=0;
            while ($i < 11) {
                $i++;
                $NomeUtente = mysql_result($result,$i,"NomeUtente");
                $Record = mysql_result($result,$i,"Record");
                $str = "AAA"
                echo "<p>AAA</p>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
```

I think I'm using the correct syntax, from the comparisons I made with other posts on this site and others. Am I wrong, or is there something else at play?

Comment: Trailing dot after the first echo, ` while (i < 11) {` missing `$`

Comment: There are numerous errors contained within this code

Answer (score 0):

Apart from you numerous errors contained within this code, you shouldn't use `echo` on a HTML document, you can simply close the PHP tag. For example

```
if( 1 == 1 ) { //True every time
?>
<p>AAA</p>
<?php } ?>
```

is almost the same as you would write :

```
if( 1 == 1 ) { //True every time
   echo "<p>AAA</p>";
}
```

Also if you want to mix HTML with PHP code, I would advise you to use `endif` and `endwhile` for your loops.

Comment: I know that, but I need to also display the content of variables, so I need the echo command to work as intended